# os.path.splitext() not working efficiently causing incorrect extension output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to split file name and file extension at specific path I am facing a problem the code is working fine in a certain way but at some point os.path.splitext() is not efficient at this point. the method is not splitting extension correctly, it's splitting the text and this cause an incorrect list for me.

This is the output when I run the code:

`['', '.pdf', '.txt', '.docx', '.jpg', '.4000 + KeyGen', '.lnk', '.3', '.9', '.ini', '.png', '.url', '.exe', '.JPG', '.PNG', '.38)', '.Trainer', '.1 + Crack', '.ME]', '.pptx']`

Notice there are some empty strings and some start with .ME although I don't have any extension at the path ends .ME or .9 etc.

What I can do is ether clean up my list with more code or adjust something in for loop to suit my needs.

Note that I am new to programming I am trying to learn as much as I can I am doing this for one week or so thanks for helping in advance.

```
import os, shutil

path = "C:\\Users\\VERX\\Desktop"

directories = []
file_names = []

# Split file name from file extension and append each one of them to its list.
for entry in os.listdir(path):
        file_name, file_type = os.path.splitext(entry)
        if file_type not in directories:
            directories.append(file_type)
        file_names.append(entry)
print(directories)
```

Comment: Can you give us a list of the files that you have in that directory? Are you sure you don't have files with those extensions? You can choose to show file extensions in the Windows settings.

Comment: I guess you need to replace `file_type` with `file_name` in both `if` sentence and `append` method.

Comment: You can do some debugging, like: `os.path.splitext('my.point.txt')` works for me in Python 3.7 and the result is: `('my.point', '.txt')`. Possibly you have hidden files too.

Comment: `os.path.splitext()` will return empty strings for file or directories in `path` that don't have extensions. You're getting directories as well as files because you're not using `os.path.isfile()`…

Comment: @martineau has already pointed out the problem. l would also suggest you to have a look at the `pathlib` module. You can easily get all the filenames using the `glob` method nd extension of each file using `suffix` method of pathlib.Path. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: Thanks to everyone I will use your advises and try them.